# Basic sorting of a multi-dimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Trying to sort an array by name so I can display an alphabetical list.

Here's a snippet of code:

```
sort($stores);

for($i=0; $i<count($stores); $i++) {
    echo $stores[$i]['name'];
}
```

I have a basic understanding of what needs to be done, I'm just not sure how to pass the 'name' part of the array to the sort() function. Perhaps I need to use a different function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [custom sort function](http://php.net/usort):

```
usort($stores, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort an array by values using a customized comparison function.

By custom here we mean an array of custom object types.

```
function compare($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}

usort($stores, "compare");
```